# Topology of Crepant Resolutions of $\mathbb{C}^3$/G

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Is there a reference that details the topology of the crepant resolutions of $\mathbb{C}^3$/G for different choices of G? I am particularly interested in the case of G=$\mathbb{Z}_{d}$

Comment: See [Crepant resolutions of 3-dimensional quotient singularities via Cox rings by Donten-Bury and Grab](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.09149) and references there.